# Flutter Firestore fetching in wrongorder even after giving orderby function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the code,

```
final Set<Polyline> _polylines = {};
  List<LatLng> latlngList = List();
  static var today = DateTime.now();
  String Daily = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(today);

  void getLocation() async {
    final location = await _firestore
        .collection('$Daily')
        .orderBy('time', descending: false)
        .getDocuments();
    for (var location in location.documents) {
      LatLng lat =
          LatLng(location.data['latittude'], location.data['longitude']);
      latlngList.add(lat);
      _polylines.add(Polyline(
          polylineId: PolylineId('adress'),
          color: Colors.blue,
          visible: true,
          width: 5,
          points: latlngList));
      setState(() {
        _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('addr'),
          position: lat,
          draggable: true,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: latlngList[0].toString(),
            snippet: '5 Star Rating',
          ),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        ));
      });
    }
  }
```

when I use this on my google map widget to display marker and polylines. It's showing in wrong order[Output Image I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akWS0.jpg) 
and real input path I added [input of marker I provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbWKM.jpg). Redlines are actually the marker I gave at the time of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing markerId

```
markerId = MarkerId('addr')
```

instead use MarkerId('adress')   or something which is having dynamic value